# Matlab Index out of bounds

Tags: matrices, matlab

I'm trying to call a function using `ode45` from another script file and I am passing in an matrix `A`. Matlab throws an error and says it can't access the matrix because it is empty. So here's the function code:

```
function out = test(t, E, A)

global N1 N2 N3;

out = zeros(1,1);

out(1) = N1*(A(1,1)*N1 + A(1,2)*N2 + A(1,3)*N3 + E(1));
```

And here's the script file:

```
global N1 N2 N3;

N1 = 10;
N2 = 10;
N3 = 10;

E = [1; 1; 1;];
A = [[0,-1,-1];[1,-1,-0.5];[1,0,-1]];

[t, L] = ode45('test', [0:.01:5], E, A);
```

When I run this Matlab throws the following error:

```
Attempted to access A(1,1); index out of bounds because size(A)=[0,0].

Error in ppsystem (line 7)
out(1) = N1*(A(1,1)*N1 + A(1,2)*N2 + A(1,3)*N3 + E(1));

Error in odearguments (line 88)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 114)
[neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs, odeFcn, ...

Error in ppsystem_script (line 11)
[t, L] = ode45('test', [0:.01:5], E, A);
```

I am so confused on why I'm getting this error, any ideas?

Comment: The 4th input parameter is for options to the solver and optional arguments start at the fifth input. You can easily fix this by passing an empty [] matrix as the 4th input.

Comment: @Daryl but then it says too many input arguments

Comment: The issue might be that ode45 runs the function 'test' over multiple times. This means that when you do "out(1) = N1*(A(1,1)*N1 + A(1,2)*N2 + A(1,3)*N3 + E(1));" then you have an E value, but no A value the next time you run ode45

Comment: @Richard do you want the A value to be constant?

Comment: @mathguy of course but I don't see how A could possibly change...

Comment: @Richard I think ode45 looks for a new value of A every time it makes 'test' run. Try making out(2) = A

Comment: @mathguy so i set `out=zeros(4,1)` and did `out(4)=A;` and i'm still getting the same error

Comment: The technique I always use is to create an anonymous function, outlined at mathworks [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html). This saves any hassle trying to do what you are doing. The link is in the context of root finding, but the same principles apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for a modified code?

```
function out = test(t, E)

    A = [0 -1 -1;1 -1 -0.5;1 0 -1];
    global N1 N2 N3;

    o1 = N1*(A(1,1)*N1 + A(1,2)*N2 + A(1,3)*N3 + E(1));
    o2 = N1*(A(2,1)*N1 + A(2,2)*N2 + A(2,3)*N3 + E(2));
    o3 = N1*(A(3,1)*N1 + A(3,2)*N2 + A(3,3)*N3 + E(3));
    out = [o1;o2;o3];
end
```

and the script:

```
clear all;

global N1 N2 N3;

N1 = 10;
N2 = 10;
N3 = 10;

E = [1;1;1];

[t, L] = ode45('test', [0:.01:5], E);
```